# Using facebook login authentication to access the website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In stead of website build-in login form, I use `Facebook` login to get user authentication, then they can browse all other page on my website.

My question is how to store user permission so that in all page, my website recognize that the current user is a authenticated user?

Is there any function in Facebook SDK provided these feature or I should use basic PHP function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SDK itself doesnt offer you such a method to store the data. You have to do this by your own. There is own programmed component that can manage such for you. It stores the access_token for the users in a database. This can directly done via ajax. You can request for users permissions and store the data in the database...in one step!

Have a look at http://www.facebook.com/pages/Helper-Component-Community/222933037808340?sk=app_412923142052609